# Time alignment of two signal with same length

Tags: signal-processing

I have found information about similar topics, but wasn´t useful for me.

I have the next 2 signals registered by a laser profilometer.
[image]

As can be seen in the picture the signals are almost equals but are not in phase. What i need is to displace the red signal over the blue one finding the more likely point of union to get a third signal.

I have tried with this code, but it does not work, i obtain zero in the lag, i suspect that it is caused becouse the signals length is the same. I am programming in MATLAB

[acor,lag] = xcorr(p2,p1);

[~,I] = max(abs(acor));

lagDiff = lag(I);

The two signals are attached.

Regards!

Comment: your series are non stationary, meaning that xcorr tool doesn't work very well in this situation. you need to remove the trend or do differencing before applying xcorr.

Comment: I tried with the detrend function and it looks better. Thanks!

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.